# Flutter: Shuffle BuiltList in Package built_value

Tags: flutter, dart, immutability, built-value

I've developed an app that receives questions from an API.
The client uses built_value for checking.

Is there a way to shuffle the objects in 
`BuiltList<Aufgabe>fragen` ?

This is what the client should do.

```
abstract class Aufgabenbundle
    implements Built<Aufgabenbundle, AufgabenbundleBuilder> {
  String get nameDerUebung;
  String get dateiNameDerPdf;
  BuiltList<Aufgabe> get fragen; //These objects should be mixed

  Aufgabenbundle._();

  factory Aufgabenbundle([updates(AufgabenbundleBuilder b)]) = _$Aufgabenbundle;

  String toJson() {
    return json
        .encode(serializers.serializeWith(Aufgabenbundle.serializer, this));
  }

  static Aufgabenbundle fromJson(String jsonString) {
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
        Aufgabenbundle.serializer, json.decode(jsonString));
  }

  static Serializer<Aufgabenbundle> get serializer => _$aufgabenbundleSerializer;
}

abstract class Aufgabe
    implements Built<Aufgabe, AufgabeBuilder> {
  String get title;
  String get frage;
  int get schwierigkeit;
  int get antwortZeit;
  BuiltList<String> get vorgegebeneAntworten;
  int get richtigeAntwort;
  @nullable
  int get angehakteWert;

  Aufgabe._();

  factory Aufgabe([updates(AufgabeBuilder b)]) = _$Aufgabe;

  static Serializer<Aufgabe> get serializer => _$aufgabeSerializer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `BuiltList` is immutable, so you can't shuffle it directly. As with other mutating operations, you need to rebuild it instead. 
When you do that, you get a `ListBuilder` which implements the `List` interface, including the `shuffle` method.

So:

```dart
  var fragen = aufgabenbundle.fragen;
  var gemischteFragen = fragen.rebuild((b) => b.shuffle());
```